# My rock paper scissors AI script isn't working

Tags: python

So Basically I've been making an AI Rock Paper Scissors script with python and it works, but only chooses Paper and I need it to choose the different things. The problem lies in between line 29 and 46. There is probably a simple fix but I cannot seem to find it. Please help me with my noobie coding.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 1

paper = 0
rock = 0
scissors = 0

plist = []

result = ""
def percentage(item, result):
    total = rock + paper + scissors
    result = item / total * 10
while x == 1:

    print(" ")
    ui = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors: ")
    if ui == "Rock":
        rock += 1
    elif ui == "Paper":
        paper += 1
    elif ui == "Scissors":
        scissors += 1



    plist.append(ui)

    plist = ["Rock", "Scissors", "Rock", "Rock", "Paper"]

    if plist[0] == "Rock":
        aio = "Paper"
        plist.pop(0)
    elif plist[0] == "Paper":
        aio = "Scissors"
        plist.pop(0)
    elif plist[0] == "Scissors":
        aio = "Rock"
        plist.pop(0)

    print(" ")
    print("AI chose " + aio)
    print(" ")
    if aio == "Rock" and ui == "Paper":
        print("You won")
    elif aio == "Paper" and ui == "Scissors":
        print("You won")
    elif aio == "Scissors" and ui == "Rock":
        print("You won")
    elif aio == "Paper" and ui == "Rock":
        print("You lost")
    elif aio == "Scissors" and ui == "Paper":
        print("You lost")
    elif aio == "Rock" and ui == "Scissors":
        print("You lost")
    elif aio == "Paper" and ui == "Paper":
        print("You tied")
    elif aio == "Scissors" and ui == "Scissors":
        print("You tied")
    elif aio == "Rock" and ui == "Rock":
        print("You tied")
```

Comment: You're setting `plist` to a static list, and then checking `plist[0]`, which is always going to be `'Rock'`.  Would that explain the behavior you're seeing?  For a fair RPS game I think you want to just do `aio = random.choice(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"])`.

Comment: Very nice AI u got there

Comment: Is the idea for the AI to pick the next throw based on the player's historical throws?

Comment: Oh -- is the idea for it to pick based on exactly what the player threw 6 moves ago, and have `plist` be a FILO queue?  If that's the idea, move the `plist = [...]` line to come **before** the while loop, so it only happens at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly your AI is supposed to be doing, but right now it's always picking `Paper` because in each loop you always do this:

```
    plist = ["Rock", "Scissors", "Rock", "Rock", "Paper"]

    if plist[0] == "Rock":
        aio = "Paper"
```

There's no way for `plist[0]` to ever be anything other than `Rock` with this code -- regardless of what you'd previously assigned to it, you're re-assigning it to this static list every time before you do your comparison (and it doesn't matter that you `pop` from it and `append` to it since you'll overwrite the whole thing before the next time you look at it).  Since it's not clear what the purpose of `plist` is, I'd suggest just getting rid of it and using `random.choice` to pick the AI's throw:

```
import random

while True:
    ui = input("\nRock, Paper, Scissors: ")
    aio = random.choice(["Rock, Paper, Scissors"])

    print(f"\nAI chose {aio}\n")
    if aio == "Rock" and ui == "Paper":
        print("You won")
    elif aio == "Paper" and ui == "Scissors":
        print("You won")
    elif aio == "Scissors" and ui == "Rock":
        print("You won")
    elif aio == "Paper" and ui == "Rock":
        print("You lost")
    elif aio == "Scissors" and ui == "Paper":
        print("You lost")
    elif aio == "Rock" and ui == "Scissors":
        print("You lost")
    elif aio == "Paper" and ui == "Paper":
        print("You tied")
    elif aio == "Scissors" and ui == "Scissors":
        print("You tied")
    elif aio == "Rock" and ui == "Rock":
        print("You tied")
    else:
        print(f"You picked {ui}, which was not one of the choices.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`plist` is defined in every loop, so `plist[0]` is always `'Rock'`.

If you remove `plist = ["Rock", "Scissors", "Rock", "Rock", "Paper"]` from the loop, it should work fine.